# WPF TabNavigate between Controls in ListView with touchkeyboard

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, keyboard, focus

I have an problem with the tabnavigation from the touchkeyboard in my listview. I want to navigate with the tab key from touchkeyboard in the listview and my listview has Items with textboxes so i want to focus only my textbox in the listview and the touchkeyboard should be open for every textboxcontrol in the listview...

with:

```
KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"
```

i focused only the item and not the control and the keybaord is closed.